# Android new android application project logcat errors

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I just creates a new android application using eclipse.When I run the project it shows following errors in logcat

```
11-04 19:19:50.928: W/WearableConn(1441): Error writing to device, error: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 5601): 

connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

11-04 19:19:50.988: I/WearableConn(1441): Socket closed

11-04 19:19:51.018: I/WearableConn(1441): Waiting 4.0 seconds to retry connection

11-04 19:19:55.068: I/WearableConn(1441): Connecting via TCP to /10.0.2.2:5601

11-04 19:20:00.028: I/ProcessStatsService(1237): Prepared write state in 6ms
```

Since I dont understand this I am a beginner need help?

Comment: in emulator or in phone?

Comment: I am testing in emulator no code have been written just running the default made project.

Comment: what android version u have set up on emulator?

Comment: thats the issue. try with 19 4.4

Comment: dont exactly know y. but this had solved my problem earlier :p. although i have answered with what i think about that.

Comment: mark the answer as helpful if it solved ur problem so that others can see that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use wearable API (Api 20 4.4W). always use Api 19 4.4. bcoz android wearable is a completely different platform. u have to make app compatible with wearable (u can use targetSDK or compile SDK to be 20) but not for the wearable.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

Go to command prompt and type as netstat and check whether port 5601 is open. if it is,then open another command prompt and type the following command telnet localhost 5554

once connected

type

redir add tcp:5601:6000
and quit

Hope this helps..

Comment: this is typical connection error @user3814490 rectify that by using this.

Comment: @Shadow he. i know this isnt fair but i have a question that is put on hold. i dont know. and i read somewhere that people with 3000+ reputation can off hold that question. will u plz do it for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763041/need-some-facebook-sdk-expert-advise-any-expert-there